# How to escape "${variable}"

Tags: nsis

I'm appending NSIS code to a temp file to include later on in the same installer:

```
...
!tempfile includeInSectionA
...
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' '<some NSIS code>$\n'
...
Section "A" SEC_A
    !include '${includeInSectionA}'
SectionEnd
...
```

Some NSIS code I want to append to the temp file contains variables (or defines, same problem) like `${variable}`:

```
Var variable
StrCpy ${variable} 'contentOfVariable'  
...
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: ${variable}"$\n'
```

The problem: the variable should expand at the time of temp file inclusion, not at the time of appending it to the temp file, because its content will have changed in the meantime:

```
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: ${variable}"$\n'
; --> DetailPrint "Variable: contentOfVariable"  ; WRONG
; --> DetailPrint "Variable: ${variable}"        ; RIGHT
```

So it must be escaped somehow.

Escaping the dollar sign and/or the brackets like follows doesn't work:

```
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: $${variable}"$\n'
; --> DetailPrint "Variable: $contentOfVariable"

!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: $\{variable}"$\n'
; --> DetailPrint "Variable: $\{variable}"

!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: $\${variable}"$\n'
; --> DetailPrint "Variable: $\contentOfVariable"
```

One solution would be to break up the variable like this is, but that's ... ugly, easy to break and hard to maintain:

```
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: $'
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' '{variable}"$\n'
```

So, how to escape "${variable}"?

Comment: ${VARIABLE} is not a variable, it is a define!

Comment: @Anders: Of course! Corrected, although irrelevant with regard to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NSIS v2 you are stuck with the DOLLAR hack you found. In NSIS v3 you can insert character codes directly:

```
Var foo
Var bar
!define VAR_FOO foo
!define VAR_BAR bar

Section
!define DOLLAR "$"
!tempfile testinc
!appendfile "${testinc}" 'DetailPrint "${DOLLAR}{VAR_FOO}"$\n'
!appendfile "${testinc}" 'DetailPrint "${U+24}{VAR_BAR}"$\n'
!include "${testinc}"
!delfile "${testinc}"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: As always, a valuable contribution, @Anders! Yes, I thought about this, but AFAIU it'd only work with Unicode installers, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, characters in the ASCII range should work everywhere. It does try to convert to the correct codepage when writing ANSI installers but the conversion might be suboptimal or fail.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this (slightly more readable) solution:

```
!define DOLLAR '$'
...
!appendfile '${includeInSectionA}' 'DetailPrint "Variable: ${DOLLAR}{variable}"$\n'
; --> DetailPrint "Variable: ${variable}"
...
```